# Memory Leaks cocos2D - spriteWithSpriteFrameName

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone

Please help me out..
I am new to cosos2D game development.
In instrument i find leaks in my game at spriteWithSpriteFrameName in the following code..

```
tileArray=[[CCArray alloc]initWithCapacity:11];
for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
@autoreleasepool {
CCSprite *encounter;
encounter = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"82x60.png"];
[self addChild:encounter z:i tag:2600+i];
encounter.position=CGPointMake(-1000,-1000);
[tileArray addObject:encounter];
}
}
```

Reply me as soon as possible. Thanks..

Comment: do you release your tileArray anywhere?

Comment: yes in dealloc method of the scene

Answer (score 0):

in ur onExit method, cleanup spritesheet, and remove all children from self.

```
-(void)onExit
 {
    [tileArray release];

    CCSpriteFrameCache *cache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];

    [cache removeSpriteFramesFromFile:@"yourSpriteSheet.plist"];

    [self removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES];

    [super onExit];


 }
```

Comment: onExit method, if i remove the sprite frames, and call recall the same scene again then my app is getting crashed, saying it is unable to find those sprite frames..even if in init method i use the following code 

CCSpriteFrameCache* frameCache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];
[frameCache addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"art.plist"];CCSpriteBatchNode* art = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"art.png"];
        [self addChild:art z:0];

Comment: add that in ur onEnter method and remove it in onExit method. Don't access it in ur scene init. Move all ur code from init to onEnter.

Comment: I moved all my code from init to onEnter method as you suggest, and my app didn't crashes but the leak issue is still there..

Comment: @rishabhjain86, using cocos2D obj.C right, so wht to use @ autoreleasepool ? already they used that inside lib. So remove that and try.

Comment: I tried that also, but it also not works.. each sprite in the above code creates leak of 432KB.

Answer (score 0):

your **tileArray** is not release that's why u r getting leaks. just set it in autorelease pool....

```
tileArray=[[[CCArray alloc]initWithCapacity:11] autorelease];
```